# Retrieving system values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This value:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemParameters2.Current}, Path=WindowNonClientFrameThickness}
```

Is usually something like `8,24,8,8` depending on your OS settings. Now, I need to retrieve the "top" value (i.e. 24 in this example) and negate that into `-24` and use it for a margin:

```
<TabControl Margin="0,-24,0,0" />
```

But how do I retrieve that value, negate it, and place it for the tab's top margin value?

If it matters, I'm using the https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just create a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) which contructs the `Margin`. (`Thickness` is a struct, so you cannot just bind the `Top` property only)